# UnmanagedMemoryStream: read and write between managed and native code

Tags: .net, stream, thread-safety, streaming, memorystream

I have been using MemoryStream  and recently found out about `UnmanagedMemoryStream which is reported to be more efficient especially when dealing with large buffers. My question is:

Can one write to `UnmanagedMemoryStream` on the native side then read from it on the managed side without having to maintain the `Position`  count of the stream on the native side, manually?

Comment: The reason for this is that, I want the writer (native code) to write from the position wherever the last writing stopped before returning to the managed side, and for the reader (managed code) to read from the position where the last reading stopped, without overwriting data, or reading old data.

Comment: This can't go anywhere, it is a pure managed class.  The only thing unmanaged about it is the underlying storage buffer.